# Removing duplicates from XML with python

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have an automatically updated XML file with format:

```
<entry>
  <title>Movie 1</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/3a6f22.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Fri Dec  3 03:02:05 2018</time>
</entry>
<entry>
  <title>Movie 2</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/ae4r12.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Fri Dec  3 05:34:06 2018</time>
</entry>
<entry>
  <title>Movie 1</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/3a6f22.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Sat Dec  4 12:04:06 2018</time>
</entry>
<entry>
  <title>Movie 3</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/3f44j2.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Sat Dec 4  14:04:07 2018</time>
</entry>
```

My desired output would be:

```
<entry>
  <title>Movie 1</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/3a6f22.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Fri Dec  3 03:02:05 2018</time>
</entry>
<entry>
  <title>Movie 2</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/ae4r12.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Fri Dec  3 05:34:06 2018</time>
</entry>
<entry>
  <title>Movie 3</title>
  <summary>pics/movies/3f44j2.jpg</summary>
  <link>IMDB link</link>
  <time>Sat Dec 4  14:04:07 2018</time>
</entry>
```

That is being read by javascript and php to make a list with CSS. I am trying to filter out any duplicates (e.g. the last entry titled Movie 1). I've searched and found some xsl / xslt solutions that I couldn't get to function properly. My problem is that I would like to remove any duplicate entries with the same title, but the summary, link, or time do not need to match.

I have tried:

```
from lxml import etree

data = open('xmlparse.xsl')
xslt_content = data.read()
xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
dom = etree.parse("movies.old.xml")
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
result = transform(dom)
f = open('movies.new.xml', 'w')
f.write(str(result))
f.close()
```

which pulls from this .xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc1" select="document('movies.old.xml')"/>
 <xsl:param name="pDoc2" select="document('movies.current.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$pDoc1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <archive>
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pDoc2/*/entry[not(name = current()/*/name)]"/>
  </archive>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

no effect though, my new output file stays empty.

I have also tried using unique_everseen but that deletes data like `<entry>` and `</entry>`, rearranges time attributes to the end of the file,  etc.. without mercy)

Comment: In order to help you, please, show us the code that is actually parsing that XML data and as well, provide us what would be the version that you would keep when you erase the duplicated entry-title as you can see, both Movie 2 have different summary.

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, it should look like this:

Comment: Okok I got the point the data will be a perfect duplicate, right?

Comment: the data will have the same <title>, may or may not have different <link> & <summary>, and will have different <time>.

I am not worried about titles that are similar but not exact, and I will probably only select based on title.

Comment: Look how fast your answer will be answered when all the information are there. I will guess 15 minutes max before to get your information. Good job on the edit champion, and thanks!

Comment: not sure what the normal speed at which questions are answered. Any tips?

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed as there is no root. Please post actual as this should fail to be parsed by any DOM compliant library like  `lxml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using XSLT 1.0's grouping method of the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Below script and demo assumes your root node is named *root*:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="title_key" match="entry" use="title"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[generate-id() = 
                                           generate-id(key('title_key', title)[1])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaGq)

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

# LOAD XML AND XSLT
dom = etree.parse('movies_old.xml')
xsl = etree.parse('xslt_script.xsl')

# TRANSFORM XML
transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(dom)

# SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('movies_new.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(result)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.. I see now that my xml is formed incorrectly -- this is the first xml file that I have created but I will read up on standard protocol. Thank you, I especially appreciate the link you provided for the write up on the Muenchian method.. so helpful.